# How do I fade out multiple images using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to fade out these 3 images on click with a 3 sec delay after clicking on the image. The code I've written currently does not work. Can someone explain why? Thank you! I thought 'this' would refer to the 3 id tags.

Also, if there is a simpler way, please share.

```
<script>

$(function(){
  ('#img1, #img2, #img3').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(3000);
  });
});
</script>


<div class="flex-container">
 <img id="img1" src="http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/images/2015/09/google_logo.jpg">
 <img id="img2" src="http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/images/2015/09/google_logo.jpg">
 <img id="img3" src="http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/images/2015/09/google_logo.jpg">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot the "$" before `('#img1, #img2, #img3')`.

Answer (score 2):

fadeOut will fade images in 3 seconds, not after 3 seconds, use

```
$('.image').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $(this).fadeOut(3000);
    }, 3000);
});
```

use common class for images, so that it can be extendable in near future.
in call back fade images.

Answer (score 1):

try this `https://jsfiddle.net/pvfbsq3q/2/`

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   $(function(){
  $('#img1,#img2,#img3').click(function() {
    $('#img1,#img2,#img3').fadeOut(3000);
  });
});});
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to use img tags as selectors as it will bind event to any image which is not required to trigger the effect.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this snippet.This is the simplest way to fade image with a delay. It fades images 3 seconds after the click event as required by you.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex-container">
 <img id="img1" src="http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/images/2015/09/google_logo.jpg">
 <img id="img2" src="http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/images/2015/09/google_logo.jpg">
 <img id="img3" src="http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/images/2015/09/google_logo.jpg">
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var selector = '#img1,#img2,#img3';
    $(selector).click(function(){
      
        $(selector).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);

    });
  
});
  

</script>
```

Comment: What if I want to do it one at a time? Rather than all 3 images being effected?

Comment: just keep the one your want in "selector" variable

Comment: Please check the updated snippet and mark it as correct answer if it solves your problem